# Getting the call response from the menu with Twilio

Tags: c#, .net, api, twilio

I am using C# to send a phone message with option(Twimlet) for the user to press 1 to confirm. How do I get the response from the call?

The code terminates prior to the call being placed, I assume I need to query the twilio server with the call sid?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
var options = new CallOptions();
options.Url = "http://twimlets.com/menu?Message=Please%20press%201%20to%20confirm%20or%20Press%202%20to%20cancel&Options%5B1%5D=http%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fmessage%3FMessage%255B0%255D%3DYou%2520have%2520confirmed%252C%2520Thank%2520you%2520good%2520bye.%26&Options%5B2%5D=http%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fmessage%3FMessage%255B0%255D%3DYou%2520have%2520selected%2520to%2520cancel.%2520Thank%2520you.%2520Good%2520bye%26&";
options.To = "+13105551212";
options.From = "+13105551213";
var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);
Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
```

Comment: You should post some code.

Comment: Code posted to my original Message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to respond to any input from the call, you need to use URLs under your control. Twimlets are pre-defined "apps" that don't give you control of the call flow outside of what you can specify in URL parameters.

The code you have now terminates because all it is doing is making an HTTP call to Twilio's servers telling it to start the call, with the `options.Url` endpoint responsible for handling that call's flow. To write a custom flow, you would need to create a public URL that returns [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) for the desired flow.

Once you've got that going, you'll use the `url` attribute of the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb to indicate where the key press data should be sent.